# Are ‘건강해라.’ and ‘아프지 말고 행복하자.’ grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

This is a part of the lyrics of a famous Korean song: [*Kim Haesol (Zion.T)*'s <양화대교 (楊花大橋; Yanghwa bridge.)>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLUvHUzd4UA).

> 행복**하자**, 우리. <sub>Let's be happy, let us.</sub>
>
> 행복**하자**, <sub>Let's be happy,</sub>
>
> 아프**지 말고**, <sub>not get sick;</sub>
>
> 아프**지 말고**, <sub>being okay,</sub>
>
> 행복**하자**. <sub>let's be happy.</sub>
>
> 행복**하자**, <sub>Let us be happy,</sub>
>
> 아프**지 말고**. <sub>not get sick.</sub>
>
> 그래, 그래. <sub>Right, alright.</sub>

---

A'ight, here comes the question:
are ‘건강해라.’ and ‘아프지 말고 행복하자.’ grammatically correct?
Can adjectives be modified with 어미 (endings) implying an ***imperative*** (commanding or suggestive) mood, in Korean?

- `건강해라`, `건강하여라`: `건강하-` (`건강하다`) + **`-여라`**. (Commanding)
- `아프지 말고`: `아프-` (`아프다`) + **`-지`** + `말-` (`말다`) + `-고`. (Suggestive)
- `행복하자`: `행복하-` (`행복하다`) + **`-자`**. (Suggestive)

Comment: **No.** They cannot.

Comment: And I'm waiting for elaborate answers.

Comment: Maybe related: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/%EC%95%84-%EC%98%88%EB%BB%90%EB%9D%BC-can-%EC%95%84-%EC%96%B4%EB%9D%BC-be-used-as-an-expression-of-surprise/3005#3005

Comment: FYI: 진화하는 우리말 "건강하세요" "행복하세요" from 한국경제신문 ( http://sgsg.hankyung.com/apps.frm/news.view?nkey=6710 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally and grammatically adjectives **cannot** be modified with 어미 implying an imperative (commanding or suggestive both).

However many Koreans are using that incorrectly when saying like:

> 건강하세요.
>
> 행복하세요.

But Korean grammar textbooks say it should be:

> 건강하시기 바랍니다.
>
> 행복하시기 바랍니다.

*Because*:

1. Adjectives cannot have endings like `-하자`,`-합시다`,`-해라`, etc.
2. It is rude to use imperative endings to elderly.

건강하다 and 행복하다 are adjectives. But you can use these instead.

> 건강해지자.
>
> 행복해지자.
>
> 건강해져라.
>
> 행복해져라.

Also `-지 말다` can only be used behind verbs.

> 졸리지 마라.

Odd!

But these issues are okay in daily lives.

Comment: Also 아프다 is also adjective.